# .Как исправить такую ошибку?

Tags: php, yii2

https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/11/18/c1f59e85d76627fdb3fb7ec757dff65b-full.png
https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/11/18/c1f59e85d76627fdb3fb7ec757dff65b-full.png

Например

> Ожидалось «none», «URL» или функция фильтра, но найдено «progid». 
>   Ошибка при парсинге значения «filter».  Потерянное объявление.
>   localhost:1064:1489
>       Элементы, соответствующие селектору: .yii-debug-toolbar__bar
>       Ожидалось «none», «URL» или функция фильтра, но найдено «progid».  Ошибка при парсинге значения «filter».  Потерянное объявление.
>   29:535:2888
>       Элементы, соответствующие селектору: .yii-debug-toolbar__block_active, .yii-debug-toolbar__ajax:hover

Comment: Совершенно не видно ошибки. Просьба сюда их в нормальном виде добавить.

Comment: Я не знаю как в ф12 увеличить шрифт чтоб лучше видно было. Текст одной ошибки скинул

Comment: Скопируй ошибку и вставь сюда, форматируй с помощью специальных средств на сайте. Можно в виде кода добавить.

Comment: Ожидалось «none», «URL» или функция фильтра, но найдено «progid».  Ошибка при парсинге значения «filter».  Потерянное объявление. 29:535:2888
Элементы, соответствующие селектору: .yii-debug-toolbar__block_active, .yii-debug-toolbar__ajax:hover